# Bon et Bien sont-ils synonymes ?

Tags: synonymes

Bonjour,
Je suis français et hier j'ai eu un débat avec des amis sur la notion de synonymes. 
On a fini par se demander si "Bon" et "Bien" sont synonymes.
Je ne trouve rien de concluant sur internet pour trancher la question.

Merci de votre aide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non. "Bien" est généralement un adverbe, alors que "bon" est généralement un adjectif, donc c'est déjà mal parti.

"Bon" n'est un adverbe que dans quelques locutions : "pour de bon", "tout de bon", "faire bon", "juger bon", "sembler bon"... Dans lesquelles on ne peut pas utiliser "bien" à la place.

"Bon" est parfois un nom : "avoir du bon", "rien de bon", "avoir du bon"... Pas grand chose à voir avec les emplois de "bien" comme nom, qui se rapportent à la morale / l'éthique ("le bien" vs "le mal"). Ici je ne parle pas des emplois de "bon" comme dans "bon de commande" ou de bien comme dans "les biens qu'on possède", parce que c'est clairement un autre usage.